# No option for creating a Visual Studio 2017 Pro VM in Azure

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-virtual-machine

I want to migrate from what I'm using to develop now

1. Windows 10 Pro in a VMWare Fusion VM
2. Visual Studio 2017 Pro license through Azure monthly subscription
3. Macbook Air 2013 1.7Ghz, 8Gb Ram

to something faster and I see I can create a Visual Studio VM in Azure, but I don't see any options for a VS Pro edition like I have. I only see a Community Edition and a Enterprise Edition for a pre built VM.

Do I select the Enterprise Edition and use that with my Pro license?
In addition, would it be better to just upload my Windows 10 image with Visual Studio already on it to Azure and just use that instead? What would be the pros/cons?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft only offers Enterprise and Community versions of Visual Studio pre-installed on Server images, see [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/using-visual-studio-vm) for more info.

If you want to use Windows 10 as the OS, then you must have a MSDN subscription, or a test pay-as-you-go subscription, and using it create the VM. In this case Windows 10 is provided mainly for development and testing purposes.

Windows 10 is not available for normal, e.g. pay-as-you-go subscriptions, or other similar.

In my opinion, if you need to use Windows 10 and Visual Studio Pro, then your best bet would be to create the image yourself and upload it to Azure.

See [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/tutorial-custom-images) for how to do that.

Comment: I'm just looking for the best solution to develop with Visual Studio. My Macbook Air doesn't seem to be cutting it anymore. I guess I have a couple options, run Windows under Bootcamp, purchase a Win Server VM with VS pre installed on Azure or upload and use my own Win 10 image with VS on a VM in Azure. Just so many options, don't know which to take.

Comment: Give Azure a try :) Personally I prefer not to use Azure VMs for developing, simply because of the relatively high ping involved. My closest (fastest) data center is 150-200ms away, which feels a bit too high for day-to-day work. However, during courses we regularly use dev machines in Azure, simply because of ease of use. For my own developing I use a physical machine running the Hyper-V envs. I need. Laptop I use can be relatively light and cheap. Machine I got for this is a Intel NUC - NUC7i7BNH with 32Gb ram. It's fast enough for VS2017 + some VMs running at the same time.